# Python Passing Class Object in to anther Class

Tags: python, oop

If I have two files `class1_file.py` and `class2_file.py` and each of them has got classes `class1` and `class2`.

class1_file.py

```
class class1:
    def dummy(self, class2):
        class2.dummy()
```

class2_file.py:

```
class class2
    def dummy(self):
        print 'hey'
```

Will I need to include: `from class2_file import class2` in to `class1_file.py` for the method in class1 `dummy` to work? I am a bit confused as I came from strong type language which requires to import classes and passing them into methods for use. But for python it seems the argument can be of any type and it will resolve it at compilation. If it is not required, how does the method in `class1` know what is coming in to the function `dummy` for `class1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to pass an object of `class2` to `class1`'s `dummy`, then to create an object of `class2` you need to import class2.

```
from class2_file import class2
class class1:
    def dummy(self, obj):      # To avoid confusion changed the variable name
        obj.dummy()

class1().dummy(class2())       # import is needed for `class2()` part only
```

Apart from that, `class2` is just a variable name, that could be anything. That is why I changed it to `obj` in this answer.

When you do `class2()` Python will look for the definition of `class2` in all the valid scopes and it will not be found. But when you do

```
from class2_file import class2
```

you are introducing `class2` as a local name in this module. So, Python would be able to recognize it.

```
    def dummy(self, class2):
        class2.dummy()
```

When you create a function like this, Python will try to execute `class2.dummy()` and it will `class2` as the parameter, not as the class, because `class2` is the nearest name in scope. And as long as the value passed for `class2` has `dummy` method, that line will be evaluated properly.

Comment: Thanks. But does that mean @zhangxaochen's answer is wrong?

Comment: @user1234440 His answer is also correct. Check the last line of my answer. He is trying to make that point only.

Answer (score 1):

no you don't have to, because in signature `def dummy(self, class2):` *class2* is just a local variable in method `dummy`. It can also be `def dummy(self, foo):` as long as `foo` is an object with method `dummy`. See [Duck typing in Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python).

Comment: This will only work if foo has a 'dummy' method right?

Answer (score 1):

Don't name the variable class2. And yes, you will need to import class2 from class2_file.

```
from class2_file import class2

class class1:
    def dummy(self, class2_obj):
        class2_obj.dummy()
```